# Map controller functions into database records in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I try to implement a chain of approval methodology in my Laravel app.

Lets say that I have a standard CRUD controller with standard REST routes.

[URL]/products

In the controller I have 3 functions (Index, Store, Update)

I want that for Store and Update a certain condition will happen before, something like that (pseudo):

```
if (fucntion requires chain of approval) {
    if (auth()->user !== one of the approvers){
        email all approvers;
        return 201 "pending approval";
    }
}

// the logged in user is allowed to execute the function
rest of the code...
```

I'm struggling with a few things here:

1. The only thing I can think of something that might be similar to this inside Laravel is the $this->authorize() function but I don't think that it was meant to be used like this, it is meant to authorize or not to authorize, not for 201 codes, and using it means aborting with 201 and it doesn't sit right
2. I want to allow the admins to control which functions need approval and because I don't want to maintain my controller functions together with a seeder that will contain a list of all the functions I'm thinking about creating an artisan command to be run before production and mapping all the functions into a database table that will be used as a model and all the process will use a proper many to many relations between the functions and the approvers, but I don't know how to map the functions with artisan command and I don't know if this is even the right way to go
3. I want to avoid from writing a certain code in all the functions that might require approval, and don't know how and if it is even possible
4. The return of the functions should return a JsonResource of the specific model for example ProductResource, What should I return when I need approval? Just to mock a proper response with status pending?

Thanks for everybody who is willing to give me some guidance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similar to below... just have a single class that defines how each user type (or even permission) is handled.

```
public function index(IndexRequest $request) // verify that use is authorized to do this action 
{
  $response = (new MyJobDirector)->handle(Auth::user());

  .. handle response
}
```

MyJobDirector Class

```
class MyJobDirector
{
  const STRATEGY = [
    'user' => 'userHandler',
    'manager' => 'managerHandler',
  ];

  public function handle(User $user): array
  {
    return $this->{static::STRATEGY[$user->role]}();
  }

  protected function userHandler(): array 
  {
    event(EmailApprovers::class);

    return [
      'code' => 201,
      'response' => 'pending approval',
    ];
  }
}
```

You can make it even more complicated by defining a separate class for each handler and specifying constants for status and a response that each class should return

```
class User extends BaseJobHandle
{
  const CODE = 201;
  const RESPONSE = 'pending approval';
}
```

```
abstract class BaseJobHandler
{
  const CODE;
  const RESPONSE;

  public function handle(): array 
  {
    $this->additionalProcesses();

    return [
      'code' => static::CODE,
      'response' => static::RESPONSE,
    ];
  }

  protected function additionalProcesses(): void {}
}
```

```
class MyJobDirector
{
  const STRATEGY = [
    'user' => User::class,
    'manager' => Manager::class,
  ];

  public function handle(User $user): array
  {
    $class = static::STRATEGY[$user->role];

    return (new $class)->handle();
  }
}
```

Regarding `The return of the functions should return a JsonResource of the specific model for example ProductResource, What should I return when I need approval? Just to mock a proper response with status pending?`

You can have a ProductResouce class, in which you decide which specific resource to return depending on a use case. It's all depends on what data you need to return.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for question 2?

Comment: I dont know why you'd want to do point 2. Also its difficult to understand it.

Comment: Each time that a user will access a certain function I need to check if this function require approval, the place I want to control the relations is the DB, but I have nothing to map between the actual controller functions and the approving groups,
How else would you map the actual controller and method to a certain group?

Comment: You can do it via middleware. For each route/route group you can define which middleware to use. You can also pass parameters to the middleware. So, assign a middleware that handles permissions and pass what permission you expect a user to have. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes

Comment: I know how to handle the permissions, Once I already have the DB with the list of all the methods I know how to handle it, my problem is that if a new coder write a new method in one of the controllers, there is no representation of this method in the DB unless some automatic or manual (preferably automatic) will insert the new method to the DB, I'm looking for an elegant way to list all the controller methods in the DB

Comment: You should create instructions on how endpoints should be protected using permissions. Those instructions should be given to new coders to read. You cant automatically secure an endpoint (controller method) unless you define somewhere how an endpoint should be protected, either in the route file, request form validator class, policy or the class it self. You can also secure controller class, i.e. to access controller X user must have permission Y, this is defined in constructor method and automatically all methods in controller class get that protection